# Android Intent - Extras not found on first load from url

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to load my application from a webpage via deep linking.

I'm using window.location to call the intent url when a webpage is hit.

The app opens fine using:
`window.location("intent://open/#Intent;scheme=testapp;package=gb.testapp.testapp;S.id=3026;end");` however, the id that I'm trying to pass in only seems to appear if the URL is loaded for a second time...

My Intent in AndoridManifest.xml is:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="testapp"  android:host="open" android:path="/" />
 </intent-filter>
```

I'm calling the following code in my MainActivity.java

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         System.out.println("URLLOAD -  " + intent.getDataString());
         if (extras != null){
             String sid = extras.getString("id");

             if (sid!=null)
             {
                 System.out.println("URLLOAD - FOUND PARAMS");
             }


         }else{
             System.out.println("URLLOAD -  NO PARAMS");
         }
}
```

This results in:
First time opening url after app install:

```
System.out﹕ URLLOAD -  testApp://open/
System.out﹕ URLLOAD -  NO PARAMS
```

Opening the URL again

```
I/System.out﹕ URLLOAD -  testApp://open/?id=3026
I/System.out﹕ URLLOAD - FOUND PARAMS
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue or can see an issue with my code?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: use `intent` parameter instead `getIntent()`

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the first time you launch your acitivty (app) the onCreate() method is being called instead of onNewIntent(). For all subsequent calls your activity is "updated" via the onNewIntent method.

Comment: The method is being called - it outputs the log.i() every time, it just doesn't detect that any parameters have been passed through

Comment: Does the intent within onCreate have any params?